# Load Custom Menu instead of Main Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I created a custom menu that display a different content. So I installed country_path module to support different locale site. So my menu has the main and main_uk. So if the url is like `site.com/en-gb` then the menu should load the main_uk menu. If it's just site.com then it will load the main menu. But I don't know how to achieve this.

Is there a way to hook the retrieval of the menu and instead load the menu based on name?

So what I was thinking is something like this

```
$locale = getLocale(); // this will return en-gb or en-us
$menu_name = "main";
if ($locale == 'en-gb') {
   $menu_name = "menu_uk";
}

// Load menu here based on it's name.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: The [context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) is probably a good candidate for this functionality. Use it to place the different menu blocks depending on locale

Comment: @2pha thanks dude.. will check this one.. Hope this will solve my issue